# How can I make a function use a variable that has been previously defined in another function in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm making code for a game that could be compared to classic DnD dungeon crawling. I have defined several dictionaries containing the statistics and inventory of a character. They look like this:

```
enemy_mid = {'hp': 100,
         'ag': 50,
         'sp': 60,
         'st': 70,
         'wep': sword,
         'arm': leather,
         'sld': buckler}
```

Currently there is one dictionary for the player, and 3 for the different difficulty levels of enemies the player can face. Now, when combat is started the function 'assign_attacker()' is called in order to decide whihc enemy the player will face. The function looks like this:

```
def assign_attacker():
attacker = character
enemy_choice = input("Would you prefer your enemnt to be easy, medium or hard, in terms of difficulty? (easy/med/hard): ").lower()
if enemy_choice == "easy":
    defender = enemy_easy
elif enemy_choice == "med":
    defender = enemy_med
elif enemy_choice == "hard":
    defender = enemy_hard
else:
    print("invalid")
```

After this function is called, the program will need to decide on who hold the initiative. It should do this using the following function:

```
def initiative():
if attacker['sp'] > defender['sp']:
    init = "att"
elif attacker['sp'] == defender['sp']:
    init = "null"
else:
    init = "def"
print(init)
```

However, when this function is called, an error comes up saying that 'attacker' is not defined. I understand that 'attacker' is a local variable and cannot be called outside the other function but I don't know what the best way is to ensure that this varaible can be called anywhere. I heard that using 'global' is very bad practice and as this variable will be used a lot later on in my code, I wanted to find out what the best way to define this variable is. This of course, also applies to the 'defender' variable.

Comment: it looks like `character` is a global variable in your script. Why not include `attacker = character` at the top of your `initiative()` function as well?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention this but it applies to the 'defender' variable as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply modify your assign attacker to return a tuple of `(attacker,defender)` and pass that to the initiative function as an argument.

```
#rest of your assign function
else:
    print("invalid")
return (attacker,defender)
```

And your initiative will look like

```
def initiative( players ) : 
    attacker = players[0]
    defender = players[1]
```

where `players=assign_attacker()` .

Comment: Where would I put     players=assign_attacker() in

Comment: Without seeing your code I would guess you have a loop that represents the game, so put in that loop after you call assign_attacker and before initiative.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a class for my game (and probably classes for things like `defender` and `attacker` as well). Here is a super simplified example:

```
class Game:

    def test(self):
        self.defender = 'hello'
        self.attacker = 'world'

    def test2(self):
        print(self.defender + self.attacker)

    def test3(self):
        self.defender = 'goodbye'

g = Game()
g.test()    # initial values set for self.defender and self.attacker
g.test2()   # prints 'helloworld'
g.test3()   # changes value of self.defender to 'goodbye'
g.test2()   # prints 'goodbyeworld'
```

The point here is that all your methods will have access to `self.defender` and `self.attacker`, and when you change these variables, the methods will be aware of these changes. You will want to make sure though, that `self.attacker` and `self.defender` and any other variable used in this way are initialized before they are accessed. For example, in the class above, if `test2()` or `test3()` is called before `test()` an error will be raised, because the variables don't exist yet. You can initialize these variables in the class's `__init__()` method, or in a `start_game()` method, e.g.:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.defender = some_initial_value
    ...
```

or you could pass in objects for the initial values:

```
def __init__(self, defender):
    self.defender = defender
    ...
```

The `__init__` method will be called when you instantiate the class (i.e., when you do `g = Game()`, or `g = Game(defender_obj)` if you are passing in an initial value.

If you are new to classes in Python, [here](https://www.codecademy.com/courses/python-intermediate-en-WL8e4/0/1) is an interactive tutorial on the subject, and here is [the Official Python tutorial on them](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).